# Java web service client giving JaxWsClientProxy.invoke error

Tags: java, apache, web-services, spring-boot, cxf

I am working on a Java web service client development . I am using STS tool and Maven apache cxf plugin , Java 1.8. While executing it , I am getting following error for JaxWsClientProxy:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Response message did not contain proper response data.
Expected: {<targetNameSpace>}ServerResponseMessage
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:161)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.createdEndDeviceControls(Unknown Source)
```

In my pom.xml I have only added the cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws for version 3.2.4 dependency.

Can someone please let me know what is the reason for this error . The method createdEndDeviceControls exists in the corresponding Port

Please Help .

Best Regards,
Sudeshna Bhattacharya